# Загрузить картинку через sprite

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет.
Картинка находятся в главном. Я их перевел на `"Sprite (2D and UI)"` так же мод сменил на`"Single"`
Далее в коде прописал следующее:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ServerImg : MonoBehaviour {

  public Image img1;

  void Update () {
        img1.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");
        // img1.GetComponent<Image>().overrideSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("2");
    }
}
```

Далее в созданной ячейке указал на img1.

Но когда я запускаю программу, картинка остается не подгруженной. А если изначально укажу картинку и перезапускаю, то изначальная картинка слетает но не заменяется на нужную.
Что я пропустил?

Comment: Она в папке "Resources"? имя верно?

Comment: @valera-kvip Они даже не папке. а все на главном лежат

Answer (score 4):

@Mr.Husky Либо поместите картинку в `"Resources"`, либо корректируйте путь в коде, так чтобы он совпал с адресом.

И попробуйте варианты:

```
img1.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load("2", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

или

```
img1.GetComponent ().sprite = (Sprite)Resources.Load ("2", typeof(Sprite));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html
Изображение должно находится в папке Resources

Comment: Вопросу год))))